# Máximo número de palabras, elegidas de los archivos de una carpeta

Tags: excel, vba

Excuse me, rookie mistake, you want to.

1. Allow to open folder which has several similar files.
2. Run the entire process indicated in the code in each file.
3. Repeat the process in the range (z7:z28) and paste the result into the cell (29,26).
4. Close all open files.

For Tim Williams: with getopenfilename choose folder and run the displayed code; the code was tested in a single file.
For Foxfire And Burns And Burns: you're right, my problem is that using getopenfilename, open the first file but don't run the code.
For Fane Dure, all books have the sheet "Teacher Sheet" and thank you for your code. Thank you all.

```vb
Sub PalabrasMaximo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim dupes As Long
    Dim maxDupes As Long
    Dim dupeWord As String
    Dim dupeTie As Boolean
     
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Ficha para docentes")
    Set rng = ws.Range("x7:x28")

    For Each cell In rng
        dupes = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, cell)
        If dupes > maxDupes Then
            maxDupes = dupes
            dupeWord = cell.Value
            dupeTie = False
        End If
        If dupes = maxDupes And InStr(1, dupeWord, cell.Value) = False Then
            dupeWord = dupeWord & ", " & cell.Value
            dupeTie = True
        End If
    Next cell
    If dupeTie = False Then MsgBox dupeWord & "" _
        & "appears in the range " & maxDupes & " times."
    If dupeTie = True Then MsgBox "The values (" & _
        dupeWord & ") appear in the range " & maxDupes & " times."
        
       Worksheets("Ficha para docentes").Cells(29, 24).Value = dupeWord

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the *specific* problem you're having getting that done?

Comment: Why `27`? How many files are there in the folder `C:\reports\week10`? Exactly 27 or could there be less, or more, files?

Comment: Step 3) is unclear in relation to the code: `Set rng = ws.Range("x7:x28")`

Comment: What is the purpose of the tag `getopenfilename` in this question? Please remove it using [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63295708/edit)

Comment: Looks like you are opening a bunch of files and counting how many times does each word appear in a list. What is the problem you re getting?

Comment: Do all the workbooks to be processed have a sheet named "Ficha para docentes"?

Comment: Then, test my code, please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next code, please. Adapted it to also process the range Z7:Z28 and return the result in `...cell (29,26)`:

```
Sub ProcessAllFolderXLXFiles()
  Dim Wb As Workbook, Path As String, wbName As String
  
  Path = "C:\Teste VBA Excel\Teste StackOverflow\TestFolder\"
  wbName = Dir(Path & "*.xlsx") 'use .xlsm, or whatever extension you want to process
  
   Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, rng1 As Range, cell As Range, dupes As Long
   Dim maxDupes As Long, dupeWord As String, dupeTie As Boolean
   
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
  Do While wbName <> ""
    Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(Path & wbName)
    Set ws = Wb.Sheets("Ficha para docentes") 'use here the sheet name, if not the one you used
  
    'use your existing code starting from ______start existing________________
    Set rng = ws.Range("x7:x28")
    Set rng1 = ws.Range("z7:z28")
    
    For Each cell In rng
        dupes = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, cell)
        If dupes > maxDupes Then
            maxDupes = dupes
            dupeWord = cell.Value
            dupeTie = False
        End If
        If dupes = maxDupes And InStr(1, dupeWord, cell.Value) = False Then
            dupeWord = dupeWord & ", " & cell.Value
            dupeTie = True
        End If
    Next cell
    If dupeTie = False Then MsgBox dupeWord & "" _
        & "appears in the X:X range " & maxDupes & " times."
    If dupeTie = True Then MsgBox "The values (" & _
        dupeWord & ") appear in the X:X range " & maxDupes & " times."
        
       ws.cells(29, 24).Value = dupeWord
       '_________________________________________stop exiting_________________
       
       dupes = 0: dupeWord = "": dupeTie = False
    'Searching in "Z7:Z:28":_________________________________________________
    For Each cell In rng1
        dupes = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng1, cell)
        If dupes > maxDupes Then
            maxDupes = dupes
            dupeWord = cell.Value
            dupeTie = False
        End If
        If dupes = maxDupes And InStr(1, dupeWord, cell.Value) = False Then
            dupeWord = dupeWord & ", " & cell.Value
            dupeTie = True
        End If
    Next cell
    If dupeTie = False Then MsgBox dupeWord & "" _
        & "appears in the Z:Z range " & maxDupes & " times."
    If dupeTie = True Then MsgBox "The values (" & _
        dupeWord & ") appear in the Z:Z range " & maxDupes & " times."
        
       ws.cells(29, 26).Value = dupeWord
       '______________________________________________________________________
       
    'close the open workbook:
    Wb.Close True
    
    'get the next workbook:
    wbName = Dir
  Loop
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks,  if you run the first part, I can't insert code to repeat the process in the range (z7:z28) and paste the result into the cell (29,26).

Comment: @Jhonny Callupe G.: Let us take it step by step: Does the above solution run your above code for all the files in the folder? If yes, no need to run the second time. Everything can be done with a single loop. But, can you confirm that it works as you want, except what you name "Repeat the process..."?

Comment: yes, it works the way I want and thank you for it.

Comment: @Jhonny Callupe G.: OK. Do you want to apply exactly the same logic, only the range to be different?

Comment: @Jhonny Callupe G.: Try the adapted code, please.

Comment: @FaneDune. Doesn't run, dialog says: "compile error: Next without For"

Comment: @Jhonny Callupe G.: It is not possible... I just tested it... I forgot to create `rng1`. I copied `rng` definition, I changed the range, but I forgot to ad 1 at the end. Corrected now. Try the updated code, please. Do not forget to refresh the page (this one) before copying...

Comment: Thank you, now if it runs, although for added security I wrote the code, thanks.

Comment: Hello, the code works like this: from a range counts the words, choose the one that repeats the most and writes it in a cell even though some are empty. The code that you kindly gave me, counts the whole range, if there is an empty cell, assumes that all are empty; In addition, in some files counts ranges with empty cells and saves a word that does not appear in that range.

Comment: @Jhonny Callupe G.: The code does what you asked in your question... It repeats the process of your existing code in all folder workbooks and do the same for the second range. I do not know what you want doing in your code...